# How to map a JSON dictionary in ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I have json data that looks like this:

```
{
  "balance": {
    "pointsEarned": 3,
    "pointsAvailable": 3,
    "pointsOnHold": 0,
    "pointsConsumed": 0,
    "nextReward": 6
  }
}
```

I'm trying to map the "balance" so I can get the other values:

```
class AccountBalance: Mappable {

  var balance: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?
   var pointsAvailable: Int?

  required init?(_ map: Map) {

  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {

    balance <- map["balance.value"]
    pointsAvailable <- map ["pointsAvailable"]
  }
}
```

According to the objectMapper [github page](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) its done this way:

ObjectMapper supports dot notation within keys for easy mapping of nested objects. Given the following JSON String:

```
"distance" : {
     "text" : "102 ft",
     "value" : 31
}
```

You can access the nested objects as follows:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    distance <- map["distance.value"]
}
```

Whenever I try and access the "balance" I get a nil. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note in the example you linked to, `distance` has a `value` property, which can be accessed with `map["distance.value"]`:

```
"distance" : {
     "text" : "102 ft",
     "value" : 31
}
```

In your example, `balance` has no sub-field called`value`, and so `map["balance.value"]` will fail.

Use `map["balance"]` to map the `balance` variable to the dictionary:

```
class AccountBalance: Mappable {

    var balance: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?
    var pointsAvailable: Int?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        balance <- map["balance"]
        pointsAvailable <- map ["pointsAvailable"]
    }
}
```